# Couldn't make breakpoint in gdb

Tags: c++, gdb, opensuse

I use openSUSE as my OS,and gdb 7.5. I want to debug my programs with gdb, with breakpoints. But when I make a breakpoint, and then run my program, gdb informs me as follows :

```
Error in re-setting breakpoint 1: malformed linespec error: unexpected string, ".cpp"
```

Its same in all of my programs. Also, when run to the breakpoint ,the program doesnt' stop at all. Can any one tell me what's wrong?

I download the latest gdb and install it ,the former message is gone ,but when  run gdb  it tells me that :

```
warning: Could not load shared library symbols for linux-gate.so.1. Do you need "set solib-search-path" or "set sysroot"?
```

how to  slove this problem?

Comment: which command are you using to set the breakpoint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a known bug in gdb 7.5 where the debugger fails to parse the linespec when the source file name starts with a decimal digit. See [this message](http://sourceware.org/ml/gdb-patches/2012-07/msg00420.html) for details.

Try renaming the file and update gdb from your distribution repository. If the bug persists, file a bug with your distribution maintainers.

See a sample session from a [bug report](http://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=14381) submitted to `gdb`  bugzilla.

```
(gdb) b 3
Breakpoint 1 at 0x4004c3: file 2.c, line 3.
(gdb) r
Starting program: /home/teawater/tmp/a.out 
Error in re-setting breakpoint 1: malformed linespec error: unexpected string, ".c"
Error in re-setting breakpoint 1: malformed linespec error: unexpected string, ".c"
Error in re-setting breakpoint 1: malformed linespec error: unexpected string, ".c"
Error in re-setting breakpoint 1: malformed linespec error: unexpected string, ".c"
```

Comment: thanks. I tried to rename the file and the message is gone and the breakpoint  works.  thank you very much.

Comment: I download the latest gdb and install it ,the former message is gone ,but when  run gdb  it tells me that :

    warning: Could not load shared library symbols for linux-gate.so.1. Do you need "set solib-search-path" or "set sysroot"?


how to  slove this problem?

Comment: `linux-gate.so.1` is not a real library, but a virtual one exported by the kernel. On 64bit systems and later kernels it was replaced with `linux-vdso.so.1`. Looks like a libc incompatibility.

Answer (score 1):

> I use "b + linenumber"

This defines a breakpoint **relative to the current line**, see als [Specifying a Location](http://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Specify-Location.html). With the code from your comment below, the following would work:

```
$ gdb ./main
(gdb) b +5
Breakpoint 1 at 0x40139c: file main.cpp, line 6.
(gdb) run
[New Thread 1528.0x1930]

Breakpoint 1, main () at main.cpp:5
5           while(scanf("%d%d",&a,&b)!=EOF)
```

Unless there is a good reason to specify relative line numbers, I suggest that you use absolute line numbers or function names:

```
(gdb) b main
Breakpoint 1 at 0x401395: file main.cpp, line 3.
```

```
(gdb) b main.cpp:6
Breakpoint 1 at 0x40139c: file main.cpp, line 6.
```

Comment: thanks for your reply .I try your code it is no problem .But consider the following simply code i used (forgive my first using stackoverflow)    I also receive the message " Error in re-setting breakpoint 1: malformed linespec error: unexpected string, ".cpp"
      #include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
 int a,b;
 while(scanf("%d%d",&a,&b)!=EOF)
  printf("%d\n",a+b);
 return 0;
}

Comment: `forgive my first using stackoverflow` - No issue :) In cases where you have additional information to clarify your question, it is better to edit the question and add it there instead of in a comment (especially code is very hard to read in comments). **One thing which we still need is the command you use to set the breakpoint.**